# How to use C# in keyword in typescript?

Tags: c#, typescript

In C# I can use IN **`in`** if condition.

```
if (1.In(1, 2)
```

How to use the `IN`  in `typescript`?

Comment: That `In` is not a keyword, it's a extension method someone added to `int` and is not part of C# or the standard libraries

Answer (score 4):

I think you want `Array.prototype.includes`

```
[1, 2].includes(1)
```